# TypeDI: class in injected service is not a function or service is not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dependency-injection, typedi

I'm using [TypeDI](https://github.com/typestack/typedi) in a Typescript ReactJS project and I need to generalize the User Repository/retrieval.

So what I did up to now is having an interface:

```
export interface IAdminUserService{
    getUsers():User[];
    getUser(id:string):User;
    ...
}
```

Have an implementation:

```
@Service('aws-user-service')
class AWSUserService implements IAdminUserService {
    ...various implementations for interface methods...
}
```

And finally, the class I'll be using, the one I should inject the other one in:

```
@Service('user-service')
export class AdminUserService{
    constructor(
        @Inject('aws-user-service') public service:AWSUserService
    ){
    }
}
```

---

Then when I need to actually use that stuff, I try to run the following:

```
const adminUserService: AdminUserService = Container.get<AdminUserService>('user-service'); // throw ServiceNotFound error
```

or the following:

```
const adminUserService: AdminUserService = Container.get<AdminUserService>(AdminUserService); // kinda good
adminUserSerivce.service.getUsers() // throws 'adminUserSerivce.service.getUsers' is not a function
```

I did put `import 'reflect-metadata';` on top of each file using TypeDI.

So now I really don't know what to do/try to make this work.
I even try to use `Container.set(<id>, <class>)` before using the `Container.get(<class|id>)` but it doesn't change anything at all.
Also tried not putting strings into the `@Service()` decorator or even putting an object like `{id:<id>}` but still, nothing seems to work properly.

Am I doing something wrong? should I fix something, somewhere?

EDIT:
Just tried the sample code from the TypeDI page and I'm getting the same exact error: `serviceInstance.injectedService.printMessage is not a function` so it might probably be something related to the library, more than my code itself.

Comment: Doesn't look like that library is maintained. Why not try https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection. You can use it in node just as you can use it in a web project and it's very elegant and simple. It supports decorators and all kinds of other DI features

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's not maintained, but the one you provided doesn't seem to be as well! The last commit is like 3 years ago. I ended up using https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe